# How to know the useful height of an iOS device in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

In some very specific cases I need to set the height of a View to the full height of the device useful area (without using flex).

I was using a hardcoded "notch height" to calculate this useful height but I just discovered that the notch can have different heights depending on the device. (3 points of difference between iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max).

Is there a way to know the useful height of a device with notch and safe area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [react-native-safe-area](https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-safe-area). it provides function to Get safe area inset top, bottom, left, right.

```
import SafeArea, { type SafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area'

//Retrieve safe area insets for root view

SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView()
.then((result) => {
   console.log(result)
   // { safeAreaInsets: { top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 34, right: 0 } }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. My only issue now is the return of the `getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView` method being a promise, given that I want to use this to set some style variables that are exported for the whole app.

Comment: await it in main.js

Comment: I have the same issue. How to implement the await?

Answer (score 11):

use 'react-native-safe-area-context'

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context#usesafeareainsets

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function Screen() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  
  console.log(insets);
  //{"bottom": 34, "left": 0, "right": 0, "top": 48}

  return <View />;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As @mohammed-ashfaq said, [react-native-safe-area](https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-safe-area) solves the problem. However, it returns the insets with a promise and I needed those values statically.

Given that, I created [react-native-static-safe-area-insets](https://github.com/Gaspard-Bruno/react-native-static-safe-area-insets) that enables access to the insets values as constants.

Comment: I dont think that you needed to do it this way, but I am totally impressed by your resolution! definitely easiest this way

Comment: I am using `react-native-static-safe-area-insets` in one of my project, thanks for the amazing contribution.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this too after I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the screen, which users phone, width and height from Dimensions component.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window'); // if you use the width you can get the screen width by pixels. And also height is the height pixels of the phone.
```

const screenWidthSomePart = width * 0,6 // Some times you can get the percentage of the screen so you can use this. screen %60

If you wanna see the safe are for the Iphone X. You can use the SafeAreaView Componenet

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
 return(
 <SafeAreaView>
   ..... // your screen componenet
 </SafeAreaView>
);
```

Comment: In iPhone XS the window height includes the size of the notch

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this without installing any packages, this is what i did.

A SafeAreaView has to be used as the wrapper of the screen with a simple View as the only child and then the rest of your desired component tree inside said View.

SafeAreaView uses padding at the top and bottom to take care of insets in devices with notch.

Then at the View inside the SafeAreaView, onLayout callback can be used to get the actual "drawable" height of the View without the insets.

The height from onLayout can then be saved to a state to do any desired logic.

```
 <SafeAreaView>
   <View onLayout={({ nativeEvent: layout }) => console.log(layout.height)}>
     {children}
   </View>
 </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Dimension module from 'react-native' like there :

```
import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native'

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height
```

Comment: In iPhone XS the `window` and `screen` height are the same and include the size of the notch

Comment: Looking at `RCTDeviceInfo.m`, line 75 reads: `typeof (dimensions.window) window = dimensions.window; // Window and Screen are considered equal for iOS.`