# React Native Bottom Bar Height

Tags: react-native

First, I am not sure if it is correct to write as Bottom Bar.

Anyhow, I am going to place a button at the bottom and it's not working as expected because of the phone.

First one is iphone 11 and 2nd is iphone 8.

So as I wanted some gap from the bottom, the first image looks good. That's what I want but 2nd image is not.
(NOTE: I am using SafeAreaView)

[image]
[image]

I've attached the code for the component. (the yellow button)

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const NextButton = ({goNext, ...props}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={goNext} style={[styles.container, props]}>
    <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/arrow_next.png')} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  image: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    backgroundColor: '#d0cf22',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});

export default memo(NextButton);
```

Comment: could you at least tell us in which way it's not working? which behaviour do you expect? and which behaviour do you observe instead? and why did you already expected it, to not work?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I've edited. I want to make it like 1st image, not 2nd one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add to @DevLover answer as he is exactly correct.  I typically might use a method similar to below for applicable screens.

`import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';`

Of which I can get the insets using in the component

`const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();`

And check bottom inset using `insets.bottom`.

Comment: `useSafeArea` is now deprecated. You should use `useSafeAreaInsets` instead. [Source](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#deprecated-apis)

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrapped that button in `SafeAreaView` so there's some space in iPhone X.

I think you should get the safe area bottom size and set the margin depends on it.

```
import SafeArea, { type SafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area'

//Retrieve safe area insets for the root view

SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView()
.then((result) => {
   console.log(result)
   // { safeAreaInsets: { top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 34, right: 0 } }
})
```

Reference : [How to know the useful height of an iOS device in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319968/how-to-know-the-useful-height-of-an-ios-device-in-react-native)